# Import data to secret from other kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I'm using a Kubernetes operator that generate original secret data. I need to use this secret in the other secret that consumed by deployment with some value mapping. I can't/won't modify Deployment to use generated secret directly. How it can be implemented?

There is few good solutions to access cluster-external secrets. May be there is custom operator/controller etc. that cat generate secret by template and values from other secret?

Details: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/97062

Comment: If RBAC permissions allow it, you can read the existing secret and write a new one, and your operator code can do whatever transformation is needed.

Comment: Thanks! I looking for existing solution or feedback that I doing something wrong. I like idea of cluster-internal secrets but how it can be bound to existing software solutions that required it own secret format? Does this problem so uncommon?

Comment: @VladimirKonkov Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: Unfortunately - no. But I discover more practical use cases and wonder how other DevOps teams solving such problem. It seems I should implement custom operator...